# Group by in Datagrid View

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

i have a scenario where i have to group the PinCode by city name like one city can have many pincode.

I have to do this in winform in datagrid. How can i do this so in datagrid i can see the + and - on before city.

I thing it can be done by nested grid. please, help.

---

### Column A   |   Column B   |   Column C

- Country

  - Zip Code  |       10,00     |       15,00
  - Zip Code  |       10,00     |       15,00
- Country

  - Zip Code  |       10,00     |       15,00
  - Zip Code  |       10,00     |       15,00

Thanks.
Shivam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen the [OutlookGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/OutlookGrid.aspx) on CodeProject?

This looks like it will allow you to expand and collapse individual rows as well as control the sort order. Because it extends the built-in `DataGridView` control, it even supports data binding!

However, it appears that nested grouping is not currently implemented, although you could look into modifying the source code yourself to add that feature if you decided an alternate presentation of your data is not appropriate.

Comment: Hi Gray, Thanks for your respond. i am using the outlook grid i just want the first level of grouping. will contact you again if i wiil face problem in Outlook grid. Hope ypo will help me..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `DataGridView` control does not support expandable/collapsible rows or nested tables. You will have to use a third party control to achieve this.

Alternatively, have a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303134056/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx), which details how to subclass the existing control. This solution does not support databinding, however, which may limit its usefulness.

Comment: But the link you send me is working but i am not bale to download the project..using (http://www.windowsforms.net/blogs/markrideout/treegridview.zip) that is inside the page

Comment: Looks like the download is no longer available (was first posted in 2006). I only have a heavily-modified version of the original code, so unfortunately I can't help further. I suggest you look into third party grid controls.

Answer (score 0):

The general concept/Logic is that, create a two distinct datatable with of-course at least one common field which is their relations. Then later, add or mix this two datatables in a dataset. Then create a data relation of the two datatable by declaring and initializing a datarelation. lastly, bind it to your Datagridview's datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeView for grouping data.